# Read CSV over FTP line by line without storing the whole file in memory/disk

Tags: python, csv, ftp, ftplib, csvreader

I'm stuck piping [`ftplib.FTP.retrlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines) to [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader)...

`FTP.retrlines` repeatedly calls a callback with a line in it, while `csv.reader` expects an iterator which returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called.

How do I combine the two things together so that I can read and process the file without reading the whole file in advance and e.g storing it in a e.g. [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)?

My problem is `FTP.retrlines` won't return until it consumed the whole file...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's not a better solution, but you can glue the `FTP.retrlines` and `csv.reader` together using iterable queue-like object. And as both the functions are synchronous, you have to run them on different threads in parallel.

Something like this:

```
from queue import Queue
from ftplib import FTP
from threading import Thread
import csv
 
ftp = FTP(host)
ftp.login(username, password)

class LineQueue:
    _queue = Queue(10)

    def add(self, s):
        print(f"Queueing line {s}")
        self._queue.put(s)
        print(f"Queued line {s}")

    def done(self):
        print("Signaling Done")
        self._queue.put(False)
        print("Signaled Done")

    def __iter__(self):
        print("Reading lines")
        while True:
            print("Reading line")
            s = self._queue.get()
            if s == False:
                print("Read all lines")
                break

            print(f"Read line {s}")
            yield s

q = LineQueue()

def download():
    ftp.retrlines("RETR /path/data.csv", q.add)
    q.done()

thread = Thread(target=download)
thread.start()

print("Reading CSV")
for entry in csv.reader(q):
    print(entry)

print("Read CSV")

thread.join()
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you! I ended up subclassing Queue directly for sake of brevity, posting my code below, in case it can be of any help

Answer (score 1):

Same solution as [Martin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118438/309917), just saved some line of code subclassing [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) directly.

```
from queue import Queue
from ftplib import FTP
from threading import Thread
import csv
 
ftp = FTP(**ftp_credentials)

class LineQueue(Queue):
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            s = self.get()
            if s is None:
                break
            yield s

    def __call__(self):
        ftp.retrlines(f"RETR {fname}", self.put)
        self.put(None)

q = LineQueue(10)

thread = Thread(target=q)
thread.start()

for entry in csv.reader(q):
    print(entry)

thread.join()
```